# I have added a mips code but when I try to plug in 100 it says grade is incorrect but i need to say incorrect when if(grade>100 ||grade<0)

Tags: mips32

I have added a mips code but when I try to plug in 100 it says grade is incorrect but i need to say incorrect when if(grade>100 ||grade<0)
please let me know how can I do my if else-statement.
the question is if(grade>100 || grade<0) output should be grade is incorrect

```
.data
enter: .asciiz "Enter an integer  : "
name: .asciiz "\n Number is incorrect. Try Again:"
gradeA: .asciiz "\n Grade is A"
gradeB: .asciiz "\n Grade is B"
gradeC: .asciiz "\n Grade is C"
gradeD: .asciiz "\n Grade is D"
gradeF: .asciiz "\n Grade is F"

.text
.globl main
main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, enter
syscall

li $v0, 5
 syscall
add $s0, $v0, $0
  
li $t1,100
blt  $s0,$t1,l1
bgt $s1,0,l1
j exit

 l1:
 la, $a0,name
 blt $s0,90,l2
la $a0,gradeA
j exit
 
 l2: 
blt $s0,80,l3
la $a0,gradeB
j exit

  l3: 
blt $s0,70,l4
la $a0,gradeC
j exit
 
 l4: 
blt $s0,60,l5
la $a0,gradeD
j exit
 
 l5: 
 la,$a0,gradeF

exit:
 li $v0, 4
   syscall
  li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

The code for loop L1 is having a line to print the non accepting cases, you can simply tackle it in a separate loop. *blt*  check if input is less than 100 and the other loops follows as they were before. The other  *bgt* loop which is mentioned in the code below check if the input is greater to hundred and diverts it to the rejecting loop  *L6*.

```
.data
enter: .asciiz "Enter an integer  : "
name: .asciiz "\n Number is incorrect. Try Again:"
gradeA: .asciiz "\n Grade is A"
gradeB: .asciiz "\n Grade is B"
gradeC: .asciiz "\n Grade is C"
gradeD: .asciiz "\n Grade is D"
gradeF: .asciiz "\n Grade is F"

.text
.globl main
main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, enter
syscall
add $s2, $zero, -1
li $v0, 5
 syscall
add $s0, $v0, $0


  
li $t1,100
blt  $s0,$t1,l1
bgt $s0,$t1,l6  ##checks if input is grater than hundread diverts to l6
ble $s0,$s2,l6
bgt $s0,0,l1
j exit

 l1:
 blt $s0,90,l2
la $a0,gradeA
j exit
 
 l2: 
blt $s0,80,l3
la $a0,gradeB
j exit

  l3: 
blt $s0,70,l4
la $a0,gradeC
j exit
 
 l4: 
blt $s0,60,l5
la $a0,gradeD
j exit
 
 l5: 
 la,$a0,gradeF
 j exit
 
 l6: 
 la,$a0,name  ##prints the case is incorrect
 j exit

exit:
 li $v0, 4
   syscall
  li $v0, 10
syscall
```

The code show incorrect number for numbers greater than 100. And for numbers less than zero it assume the grade to be F. If you want the code to  indicate incorrect number for negative numbers or float numbers less than zero you can visit :
*http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~jorgev/cs333/reference.html*
and
*https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/downloads-mips/documents/MIPS_Warrior_M5150_SoftwareUserManual_MD00980_01.05.pdf*

For this you have to change the code to float input and use  *sltu* to have an *hi* or *lo* register and compare them to get the required error displayed on console.
You can also compare a negative lower limit to the input using *ble*.